# Other word for negative impact

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, academia

Can anyone give me a scholarly term that describes "negative impact"? It's for a title: the negative impact of colonialism on mentality

Comment: "Negative impact" ;-)

Comment: What's the phrase you're trying to complete?

Comment: It's for a title: the negative impact of colonialism on mentality

Comment: What's not "scholarly" about *negative impact*?

Comment: The draft title seems almost a parody of the worst sort of academese: three abstract nouns, each being the nominalization of a verb, and  the use of *negative* to mean simply *bad.* (Using *positive* and *negative* for *good* and *bad* is pretentious, not merely in substituting longer words for perfectly serviceable shorter ones, but even more in pretending to scientific objectivity—which would exclude value judgments—in the very act of making a value judgment.) My suggestion would be to use *harm* —as a verb.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a good choice would be [detriment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/detriment) or some variation of it.

> 2. the negative result caused by something that creates difficulty for achieving success

In regards to the title, "the negative impact of colonialism on mentality", you could turn it into "the detrimental effect of colonialism on mentality" or "the detriment to mentality caused by colonialism", for example.

I do think "impact of colonialism on mentality" is a weird phrase, though. Mentality in regards to what? Maybe you should say "impact of colonialism on mental state"?

Comment: Not sure if "mentality" vs "mental state" is all that weird mostly because "mentality" refers to a way of thinking and "mental state" refers to a state of mind i.e. depression, happiness, angst, hope (not as emotions but as conditions) etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what mentality refers to either, I just think the sentence sounds a little off without more context.